# hasManyThrough relationship in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have the following struct:

```
Order
 id

Order_Products
 id
 order_id
 product_id

Products
 id
```

Im trying to use hasManyTrough (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

I have something like

```
class Order extends Model{
...
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\OrderProduct', 'product_id', 'id', 'order_id', 'id');
}
...
}
```

I can not make it work. I'm confused, can someone help me.

Comment: A single pivot table like that is a `belongsToMany`, not a `hasManyThrough`. Your relationship should be between `Order` and `Product` models, and generally you don't have a model for the `pivot`, `OrderProduct` in this case.

Comment: ohh thanks, this works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tim Lewis, I needed belongsToMany, cause order_products is pivot table. Something like this.

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'order_products', 'order_id', 'product_id');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to use `belongsToMany` relation.

---

#### A little bit about `Has Many Through`.

Tables:

```
Product
 id

Order
 id
 product_id

Order_Category
 id
 order_id
```

in this case you can get `Order Categories` for `Product`

```
class Product {
  // ...

  order_categories() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Post', 'App\User');
  }

  // ...
}
```

Laravel doing something like this.

```
$orderIds = Order::query()
  ->where('product_id', $product->id)
  ->get(['id'])
  ->pluck('id');

$orderCategories = OrderCategory::query()
  ->whereIn('order_id', $orderIds)
  ->get();
```